# Code hangs when nc_open_par() fuction is called

Tags: netcdf, openmpi

I am using parallel NetCDF functions (NetCDF compiled with HDF5 parallel enabled), and my code hangs in the part where `nc_open_par()` is called. It does not give any error messages.  My code worked in the past, I don't quite remember what version of NetCDF I have used in the past, but it never hanged when the `nc_open_par()` was called.

I am using the following setup.

HDF5 1.14.1-2

OpenMPI 4.1.5

NetCDF 4.9.2

And this is the netcdf info from `nc-config --all`

```
This netCDF 4.9.2 has been built with the following features:

  --cc            -> mpicc
  --cflags        -> -I/usr/include
  --libs          -> -L/usr/lib -lnetcdf
  --static        -> -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm -lz -lsz -lbz2 -lzstd -lxml2 -lcurl
  --has-dap          -> yes
  --has-dap2         -> yes
  --has-dap4         -> yes
  --has-nc2          -> yes
  --has-nc4          -> yes
  --has-hdf5         -> yes
  --has-hdf4         -> no
  --has-logging      -> no
  --has-pnetcdf      -> no
  --has-szlib        -> yes
  --has-cdf5         -> yes
  --has-parallel4    -> yes
  --has-parallel     -> yes
  --has-nczarr       -> yes
  --has-zstd         -> yes
  --has-benchmarks   -> no
  --has-multifilters -> yes
  --has-stdfilters   -> deflate bz2 zstd
  --has-quantize     -> yes

  --prefix           -> /usr
  --includedir       -> /usr/include
  --libdir           -> /usr/lib
  --plugindir        ->
  --version          -> netCDF 4.9.2
```